# How to compile or run Kumo cli on php server w/ jdk and jre installed

Tags: java, github, word-cloud

I want to generate text cloud on my php server.  I found Kumo in github and that seems promising.  It is https://github.com/kennycason/kumo .

The problem that I have is how to build the jar file / use kumo on the server.  I don't intend to install any java IDE as I think jdk / jre should provide me the necessary tools to compile/make the jar file.  But I am not sure how to do it correctly on php server. And unfortunately, there is no doc there in github telling me how to do it.

After getting the cli, I intend to use the cli to interface with my php script.

Comment: The repository contains a Maven *pom.xml* file. Have you tried using that to build it?

Comment: Also if you look into the *brew* install script ["kumo/script/kumo.rb"](https://github.com/kennycason/kumo/blob/master/script/kumo.rb) it is downloading a precompiled jar file from [here](https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/kennycason/kumo/1.7/)

Comment: @UnholySheep   thx for your help, I can get kumo cli running on my server.

Do you know how to build the jar file from the github source using JDK?

Comment: As I already mentioned, the project seems to be using Maven. You need to install that (refer to their [documentation](http://maven.apache.org/)) and then you should only need to execute `mvn package` inside the directory (where the *pom.xml* file is)